# Problem with a script that pushes automatically

Tags: bash, git, github

I'd like to use git to backup some important data. To do so, I made this script (use ssh to authenticate so don't need to insert my credentials).

```
cd /media/patrick/Data
/usr/bin/inotifywait -m /media/patrick/Data -e create -e move -e modify -e delete |
   while read path action file; do
       git add *
       git commit -m ‘”$(date)” file “$file” appeared in the directory “$path”  via “$action”’
       git push -u origin master
   done
```

But this doesn't work, it seems that git tries to add what's in the commit message.
I get this error:

```
error: pathspec '31' did not match any file(s) known to git
error: pathspec 'Jul' did not match any file(s) known to git
error: pathspec '2020' did not match any file(s) known to git
error: pathspec '07:57:58' did not match any file(s) known to git
error: pathspec 'PM' did not match any file(s) known to git
error: pathspec 'CEST”' did not match any file(s) known to git
error: pathspec 'file' did not match any file(s) known to git
error: pathspec '“test”' did not match any file(s) known to git
error: pathspec 'in' did not match any file(s) known to git
error: pathspec 'the' did not match any file(s) known to git
error: pathspec 'directory' did not match any file(s) known to git
error: pathspec '“/media/patrick/Data/”' did not match any file(s) known to git
error: pathspec 'modified/created/removed' did not match any file(s) known to git
error: pathspec 'via' did not match any file(s) known to git
error: pathspec '“MOVED_FROM”’' did not match any file(s) known to git
Branch 'master' set up to track remote branch 'master' from 'origin'.
Everything up-to-date
```

Have no idea about the reason, sorry but i'm not used to shell. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your commit message should be in quotation marks if you want to use quotation marks in you commit message you have to escape them:

```
git commit -m "\"$(date)\" file \"$file\" appeared in the directory \"$path\" via \"$actionv\""
```